# SwiftUI Scrollview with LazyVStack hangs on data change

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

We have an app that displays a list of around 10,000 rows and find that the performance is great when scrolling through the data. However, when the data is refreshed (even if it's just one row that has data changed) we find that the app can sometimes hang for up to 10 seconds. The same can happen when a user types to filter the list and then clears search keywords.

The view is roughly:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ModelsViewModel
    ...

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeaderView(...)
            ScrollView {
                if !viewModel.models.isEmpty {
                    ModelListView(models: viewModel.models)
                } else {
                    Text("No content - pull to refresh")
                }
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}


struct ModelListView: View {
    
    let models: [ModelManagedObject]
    ...

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(models) { model in
                Button {
                    // perform some action
                } label: {
                    // Label view
                    ...
                }
                .id(model.guid)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen some suggestions where `.id(UUID())` is added to the `LazyVStack` (e.g., suggested by Paul from [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui)). This fixes the hangs, but makes the view itself unusable as we offer functionality on each row (e.g., allow user to download some of the model data from the server and we show download indicators) so we don't want to destroy the entire list.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered these sorts of performance issues and has been able to find a workaround? The issue has had be stumped for days!

Comment: Unfortunately this is tough to debug this with the limited code provided. It could be related to many factors. Is there a way you could provide working code that when run exhibits the behavior you described?

Comment: Thank you - I'll try to put together a better example tomorrow. I'm wondering though, should `ScrollView` & `LazyVStack` perform well when data changes? Is the problem that others have encountered limited to `List`?

Comment: why not `ForEach(models, id: \.self)` while making `ModelManagedObject` to conform to `Identifiable`? I don't think it will resolve all the issues, but it will definitely help the efficiency of the layout

Comment: any news/updates or maybe solutions?